# Make rented Server appear inside local network

Tags: linux, networking

My question is if it is possible to make a rented (external) server appear inside my local network, so that the server can comunicate with all my local devices.

I'm currently running a raspberry Pi inside my local network as a HomeKit Bridge and because I have running a webserver on digital ocean I thougt it would be very interesting making that digital ocean server available inside my local network and run the Homekit Bridge on it, but i didn't came up with a solution. Maybe sb. has an answer to my question!?

Comment: Why would you even want to do this?!

Comment: Because I don't want to run my raspberry pi all the time and because I already have a server, I thought it would be great if the server could handle that task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible with VPN software, like OpenVPN.

You would need to have a VPN server in your local network, and then connect external server to that VPN server, as VPN client, to see devices with private IPs of the local network.

You can also install VPN server on external server, and then make one device in your local network, a VPN client, which routes traffic to external server.

Depending on what router you have on your local network, it is possible that is has some type of VPN server or client software on it.

Comment: All right so I will need to have a local server running either way. Than I can leave it as it is. :) Thanks for your quick reply!

Comment: Well, potentially whatever you are using as a router/firewall for your network could potentially have a VPN service on it.

Answer (score 1):

OpenVPN is a great solution, but a perhaps more straightforward way that you probably already have software to do would be a forwarded port through an SSH Tunnel.  you'd connect to your external server from a server on the local network, providing an argument to forward a given port to on the local ssh client to a given port on the remote ssh server.

`ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 user@my-mysql-server.addr -f -N`

See http://blog.trackets.com/2014/05/17/ssh-tunnel-local-and-remote-port-forwarding-explained-with-examples.html for further info.

SSH tunnels are a great solution for scenarios where you don't want a complex VPN setup to just open one port.  They start to be a bigger pain if you need multiple ports open or have many clients.    But for you, I think something like this would work well, assuming you have a system on the local machine ( maybe even the pi itself!)  which can initiate the tunnel.